# What is the recent change to eqnarray for?

Tags: eqnarray

Looking at the PDF of the current LaTeX source, I noticed that very recently (2021-10-14, I believe), the standard definition of the `eqnarray` environment was changed to "explicitly set `\@currentcounter`". It seems that the command `\def\@currentcounter{equation}` was added to the definition of `\eqnarray`. What does this change accomplish? Was anything else changed in the definition of the `eqnarray` environment? Just wondering.

Comment: this was done to help external package to identify the last counter that was changed, see https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/300

Comment: note that change or no change, the same advice holds: don't use `eqnarray`, use the alignment environments from amsmath

Comment: So how often was something coming out wrong before this change? Was it mainly a problem with `zref`, or was it a problem with basic LaTeX with no extra packages at all?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because the package might have been having some *really specific* error when used with a *really specific* other package.

As you said, that's just an explicit definition of the environment counter (I believe for referring the equations in the array). I don't know exactly how it was before, but they might had been using this counter from elsewhere or in a different way. Probably, this is safer than the older version, even though it wasn't an actual problem.

Comment: I read the comments above, I also suggest you to use `align` instead of `eqnarray`, in general.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  While not really wrong, I'm afraid your answer doesn't actually answer the question.  You could instead summarise the [github issue](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/300) Ulrike mentioned in her comment, which was the issue that motivated this change (although the actual change to `eqnarray` was done for a [later issue](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/687))